# present, past, passive and perfect participle usages

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles, perfect-aspect, present-participles, progressive-aspect

Which is correct grammatically?

1. Beaten severely, he died immediately. [*past participle*]
2. Having been beaten severely, he died immediately. [perfect participle)

I would like to put my understanding of the sentences. please correct me if I am wrong. According to me sentence 1 implies that "He was beaten severely. So, he died immediately" a case of" cause and effect".as per Past participle definition. Sentence 2 implies that "He having been beaten severely. he died immediately".(or) "After he was beaten severely. He died immediately." A case of perfect participle which indicates completion of first action before start of second action. I request you to give me explanation if I am wrong or I am correct

Comment: (1) is a deleted form of (2); both are fine, as no ambiguity is introduced by this particular deletion. // (3) is unacceptable.

Comment: As I am not native speaker, I would like to put my understanding of the sentences. please correct me if I am wrong. According to me sentence 1 implies that "He was beaten severely. So, he died immediately" a case of" cause and effect".as per Past participle definition. Sentence 2 implies that "He having been beaten severely. he died immediately".(or) "After he was beaten severely. He died immediately." A case of perfect participle which indicates completion of first action before start of second action. I request you to give me explanation if I am wrong or I am correct

Comment: There's an implied causality (demanding logical reasoning on the part of the reader) in both variants in this particular example. There's an implied 'because' when one looks at the pragmatics (how experienced Anglophones actually use the language) in both sentences. I'd say these sentences mean almost exactly the same thing. This is not always true. You might find my answer to [What are possible semantics of participle constructions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508671/what-are-possible-semantics-of-participle-constructions/508765#508765) helpful, though it looks at absolutes.

Comment: Both are closer in interpreting the meaning. But I have a doubt.  When we say "Beaten severely, he died immediately" can't it be interpreted as "Being beaten/ Having been beaten...." Can the main clause always express the intended meaning?

Comment: As per me, grammatically both the sentences are correct. But they have different meaning with the change in structure of the sentence.